# Loop through column and when empty cell is found, color entire row?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I want to loop through a column, and when i find an empty cell, or a cell containing a specific number, that entire row to be colored in.

What i have tried is this (and some variations of this), but it does not work:

```
xl.Range end = MySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xl.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
xl.Range start = MySheet.get_Range("Q2", end );

if (start.Value == null)
{
    start.EntireRow.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
}
```

Any sort of help or any good idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this Excel VBA?

Comment: if you want to loop through the cells then you need a loop IE: For Each, For or while statement.

Comment: @D.O. No, it's C# Interop - Excel

Comment: Then your question must be in "C# questions" not in "Excel questions"

Comment: @D.O. it's under c# and excel, also office interop and excel-interop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE :**

Found the solution to this :

```
 xl.Range first_range = MySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xl.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
        xl.Range usedRange = MySheet.get_Range("Q2", first_range);
        xl.Range rows = usedRange.Rows;

 int count = 0;
        foreach (xl.Range row in rows)
        {
            if (count > 0)
            {
                xl.Range firstcell = row.Cells[1];    
                string firstCellValue = firstcell.Value as string;    
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstCellValue))
                {
                    row.EntireRow.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

when using for & foreach loops with big data like 10000 rows i get

> "OutOfMemory " exception

so the best solution is using Lambda Expressions

```
 //best practice access cell by number not by string

 yourWorksheet.RangeUsed().Rows(r => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Cell(1).Value.ToString()))
                         .ForEach(r => r.Style.Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.Red));
```